# Launch my app from chrome

Tags: android

I've seen a few websites that if they have an app installed on my phone, if I load there site I get the option to open there app. How is this achieved as I would like to put this into my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They register a receiver in their manifest like so

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="" android:host="" android:path=""/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

where `scheme` can be http, `host` can be a website and `path` can be a folder or something

example:

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="site.something" android:path="aPath"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

would be triggered when you go to the website http://site.something/aPath

You need to add this piece of code to the activity that should be opened when the URL is requested

Comment: Thanks, so `/news` could load up `NewsActivity`, and `/contact` could load up `ContactActivity` I just need a separate intent filter for each URL I want to load?

Comment: Yes that is definitely possible. You declare a `NewsActivity` with an `/news` intent-filter and a `ContactActivity` with a `/contact` intent-filter

Comment: Just added this code, and it's not giving me the chooser, but neither is the first site where I noticed this. Is it possible to reset Chrome to give me the picker do you know?

Comment: If the chooser isn't shown, I don't think that there is anything you can change in chrome to show the chooser. The chooser is only shown when multiple apps on the device can handle the intent. If there is only one app that can handle the intent, the chooser isn't shown.

Comment: The problem was I was typing the URL in directly, and not clicking on a link, once I clicked a link (on Google) it asked me to load it and worked fine :).

Answer (score 1):

you can do so by making your activity browsable for that you need to add below code in your menifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivityName"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="host.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

and whenever any link that contains http://host.com/ will be clicked then android will show your application as a one of the option that can open this link. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

On webpage there is a script that detects OS platform and shows a popup to open the Google Play.
In the application you have to register IntentFilter (in manifest) that cause URL interception for your webpage so, when you click on some link system will ask you if you prefer open it with application, or using browser.